# Macros not recognized in ios

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have set PaidApp =1 in my preprocessor macro.
But when i am trying to implement it in my appdelegate file like below:-

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{

        m_bootup = 1;
        m_showhint = 1; // show hand hint on bootload level 1 only

#ifdef PaidApp
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"adDisabled"];

#endif




}
```

the compiler just skips it... it does not go into the ifdef condition
i am not getting why this is happening

The below link show how i have defined my macro :-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tDQP.png

And this shows how i have used it :-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED2i8.png

Comment: How did you set the preprocessor macro? Did you do it for both debug and release builds?

Comment: yes i did it for both

Comment: You can use #define PaidApp 1 and in your app delegate you can use #if PaidApp ... #endif

Comment: i want my project to be free and paid for which what i have done is ... if we select free version Ads should come and if Paid then no Ads (made two targets)... it is working in rest all my projects , whats wrong in this one i cant really find..

Comment: i want the macros to be set in the build settings only

Comment: post a screenshot of your build settings so we can see how you defined the preprocessor macro. Perhaps you put it in the wrong setting or forgot to add = in between or you only set it in the project build settings but the targets override it without inheriting the projects preprocessor macros

Comment: i have provided the links of screenshots in my question now..